# Как правильно вывести из XML данные

Tags: php, xml

Offer - это товар. У одного товара есть идентификатор `<vendorCode>` НО! Этот вендор разделен, то есть у него есть еще offer с другими размерами. То есть, как вывести один оффер по `<vendorCode>` и к нему все размеры с других offe - ров с одинаковыми `<vendorCode>`. Больше не пойму как объяснить.

Вывожу так:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file('test.xml');

for ($i=0; $i < 30; $i++) { 

        echo $xml->shop->offers->offer[$i]->name . "<br>";
}
```

Сам XML:

```
<offer id="38369" type="vendor.model" available="true">
        <name>name</name>
        <price>2095</price>
        <oldprice>2990</oldprice>
        <currencyId>RUR</currencyId>
        <categoryId>5</categoryId>
        <delivery>true</delivery>
        <vendor>Nike</vendor>
        <vendorCode>9132</vendorCode>
        <model>Скейтбординг</model>
        <param name="Размер" unit="RU">36</param>
        <param name="Пол">Женский</param>
        <param name="Возраст">Взрослый</param>
</offer>
```

Comment: полный пример XML демонстрирующий задачу представьте, а не кусочек. и опишите желаемый результат.

Comment: @teran например в каждом offer есть `<name>` И он в несколькоих offer одинаковый, например в 1 - nike , 2-nike 3 - adidas . Хочу результат Nike, Adidas

Comment: Вам сложно расширить пример XML чтобы там было несколько `offer` или что? Отредактируйте вопрос (_[edit]_), добавьте туда более полный XML, включающий еще и `<shop>`.